# How many S3 List requests are happening on a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way where we can check how many S3 List requests are happening on a bucket

Comment: Perhaps you can refer to this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/configure-metrics.html?shortFooter=true) given on official docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution on AWS to finding out what is going on at the API level is to use [CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/).

See [Logging Amazon S3 API Calls by Using AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by enabling the request metrics on S3 bucket by using CloudWatch service. The metrics are available at 1-minute intervals after some latency to process. These CloudWatch metrics are billed at the same rate as the Amazon CloudWatch Custom Metrics.

You can refer this [Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/configure-metrics.html?shortFooter=true) to Configure Request Metrics for an S3 Bucket.